# Selecting highest value from with a grouped by query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query:

```
select substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total from
dq.data 
group by points,location order by location,total desc
```

Which produces this data:

```
FRANCE  |0|2|0|0|0|0|1  110.0    
FRANCE  |0|2|1|0|1|2|1  100.0    
FRANCE  |0|2|0|0|0|1|1  100.0    
FRANCE  |0|2|1|0|0|1|1  100.0    
FRANCE  |0|2|0|1|1|2|1  100.0    
FRANCE  |0|2|0|0|1|1|1  100.0
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|1|0  120.0    
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|0|0  110.0    
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|2|0  110.0    
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|0|2  110.0    
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|1|1  110.0
```

I want to get to highest `total` and the related `points` for each `location`.

I should end up with:

```
FRANCE  |0|2|0|0|0|0|1  110.0
GERMANY |1|0|2|2|2|1|0  120.0
```

I believe I need to use a subquery and `MAX(total)`, but I cant get this to work.
In the subquery, I want to select `points`, but I dont want to group by it which is obviously not allowed.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instincts are correct.  You can do this by calculating the max total and then joining this back to the original data:

```
select t.*
from (select substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total
      from dq.data 
      group by points,location
     ) t join
     (select location, max(total) as maxtotal
      from (select substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total
            from dq.data 
            group by points,location
           ) t
      group by location
     ) tsum
     on t.location = tsum.location and t.total = tsum.maxtotal
```

Note that this version will return duplicates if there are ties at the top.

I am not intimately familiar with google-biggquery.  If it supports the "with" statement, then you can simplify the query, by doing:

```
with t as (select substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total
           from dq.data 
           group by points,location
          )
select t.*
from t join
     (select location, max(total) as maxtotal
      from t
      group by location
     ) tsum
     on t.location = tsum.location and t.total = tsum.maxtotal
```

If it supports windows functions (such as row_number()), then you can eliminate the explicit join altogether.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will give this a go. It doesnt support row_number() and it also doesnt allow you to select * (or t.* i think). I assume I can just hardcode the names of the fields?

Comment: Hardocing the fields is the correct option.  I just use the "*" in answers because it is faster to type.  In general, though, you want to be explicit about field names.

Comment: Thats fine - ill give it a go, report back and if all is well, I will accept at that point. Thanks again

Comment: Im getting this message, unfortunately no line number:BAD_QUERY (Invalid mixture of aggregations and non-aggregated fields in SELECT clause)

Comment: Oops, I left out a group by in the subquery.  Add in "group by location".

Comment: Thanks for the correction - everything seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Gordon, could you please point me in the right direction if I have duplicates at the top as you state? If they are equal, it doesnt matter which one it displays. Thanks

Comment: There are two ways.  The easier way is using a function such as row_number() or rank().  Does google big-query support these functions?

Comment: Doesnt look like it :(  https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, solved it similar to this:

```
SELECT substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total
FROM ( 
   SELECT * FROM dq.data ORDER BY location,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10)) desc 
) tmp
GROUP BY points,location;
```

Not sure if it will work as my db was MySQL, but it's a nice intuitive solution.  Order the subquery the way you want the summary rows to fall out.

Comment: Standard SQL does not support "order by" in subqueries, so this will not work on mst databases.

Comment: I got: BAD_QUERY (location appears in ORDER BY, but it is not a named column in SELECT) and then when explicitly stating it: BAD_QUERY (expression SUM(IF([p1] = [r1], 10, - 10), DESC) in ORDER BY is invalid)

Comment: SELECT substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total
FROM ( 
   SELECT substr(name,7,50) as location, points,sum(if (p1=r1,10,-10))as total FROM dq.data ORDER BY location,total desc 
) tmp
GROUP BY points,location;

Comment: couldn't find anything definitive on whether google biqquery supports order by in a subquery?